# Which is better to use android-support-v7-appcompat or appcompat

Tags: android

My project uses `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, `DrawerLayout`,`GoogleMap` using `FragmentActivity`, custom activity theme extending `Theme.Holo` and ActionBar extending `Widget.Holo.ActionBar`

For that, I needed to add either `appcompat_v7` or `android-support-v7-appcompat`.

Min sdk 14 and target 21.

So between those two, which is better to use considering future compatibility and performance?

And please don't post answers with links to Android documentation and asking me to read that whole documentation. Or is there any third better option available?

Comment: With such a high minSdkVersion, I guess you don't need the support libraries - at least,  if you don't you need to use the Material design theme on lower than Lollipop devices.

Comment: @DerGolem yes, u r right, with that minSdkVersion, no need of library, but I'm also not wrong totally, because I had 1 item in styles.xml "<item name="contentInsetLeft">10dp</item>" and only for this i needed the library, but because of your comment I removed the item and got rid of library. But you shouldn't down vote this question

Comment: It must be happened by mistake, sorry (sometimes my finger is faster than my eye). Random clicks may happen. Reverted ;)

Comment: it's ok... :) but 1 weird thing happening... I can now run my project in debug mode through eclipse withut that lib, but when i try to export signed apk, error comes saying missing v7-appcompact library and which goes away only after adding the library

Comment: now I'm facing this issue(android bug) https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72760 Sometimes, i just hate Android+Eclipse :(

Comment: I think you can simply remove the offending `<item name="contentInsetLeft">10dp</item>` line from the theme or style you are actually using. If it's a **yellow** Lint message, then it's `not an error`, but a **warning**. It does no harm. By the way, I hate Android Studio, and love Eclipse. ;)

Comment: yes, I removed that line, but still even after lot of project cleaning and eclipse restarting, eclipse want that v7 library added for exporting the signed apk

Comment: Do you use Material design (or some other feature which have been introduced with Lollipop) on earlier versions of the API level? If so, I guess you can't get rid of it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Actually i don't know about "Material Design", and the issue is when I remove the lib, it doesn't show exactly where the lib required, but just 1 error... but I have to find out where the lib is exactly required

Comment: Material Design is the name of the new theme introduced with Lollipop. https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wut? there is no difference at all, it's the same... Eclipse while importing `android-support-v7-appcompat` project into workspace naming it `appcompat_v7`, maybe it confused you...

current (should be newest, downloaded by SDK Manager) support projects are located inside your sdk directory in `sdk\extras\android\support` path

list of support libs is [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html), yes, it's documentation...

Comment: OK... :O, when I try to add library, it shows 2 options, and last few days, I'm having my lot of time wasted behind removing these library related errors... :( I think I have to read the documentation... :D By d way, upvote

Comment: note that there is "few" v7 support libs... but appcompat is one and only, other v7 contains e.g. widgets